# Custom telephone call app for Sony SmartBand Talk SWR30

Tags: sony-smartwatch

We are currently evaluating wearables for a new product. The Sony SmartBand Talk SWR30 seems to be the perfect fit for our needs.

Unfortunately we could not figure out how to program custom apps for the SmartBand Talk SWR30. More specifically we need to control telephone calls from the watch (start preconfigured calls, stop the call after some time and start another call).

Is there a way to achieve this with the SmartBand Talk SWR30?

Answer (score 0):

SmartBand Talk SDK has not been published publicly yet. It is available only to partners.

For details regarding partnership, you can contact through email.

You can find email address under "Other Developer Questions" section on this page:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/about/how-do-i-get-in-contact/